# WinAPI GetWindowInfo and GetWindowRect Returning Values of 0

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

So here is what is happening. I am using User32 to use the FindWindowA function, where my test case is Notepad (i.e. "Untitled - Notepad"). I then use several other functions like GetWindowInfo and GetWindowRect, and the values returned are strangely all 0. So here is what I do in Java:

```
Pointer windowHandle = user32.FindWindowA(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
System.out.println(windowHandle == null ? "Pointer is NULL" : "Pointer is valid.");

WinAPI.WINDOWINFO windowInfo = new WinAPI.WINDOWINFO();
Pointer windowInfoPtr = windowInfo.getPointer();
System.out.println("result of GetWindowInfo: " + user32.GetWindowInfo(windowHandle, windowInfoPtr));

System.out.println(windowInfo.cbSize);
System.out.println(windowInfo.dwWindowStatus);
System.out.println(windowInfo.dwStyle);

WinAPI.RECT rcWindow = windowInfo.rcWindow;
System.out.println(rcWindow.bottom.longValue() + ", " + rcWindow.left.longValue() + ", " + rcWindow.right.longValue() + ", " + rcWindow.top.longValue());

WinAPI.RECT r = new WinAPI.RECT();
Pointer rPtr = r.getPointer();

System.out.println("result of GetWindowRect: " + user32.GetWindowRect(windowHandle, rPtr));

System.out.println(r.top + ", " + r.left + ", " + r.bottom + ", " + r.right);
```

The output results in this:

```
Pointer is valid.
result of GetWindowInfo: true
60
0
0
0, 0, 0, 0
result of GetWindowRect: true
0, 0, 0, 0
```

I used Notepad as a test case because it's just a base, one-window program. Why am I getting "0" for everyone of these values? The window handle is clearly not null, and in theory should work.

For extra information, here are my structs that I made for JNA so it would map them:

```
    public static class WINDOWINFO extends Structure {
        public int cbSize = this.size();
        public RECT rcWindow;
        public RECT rcClient;
        public int dwStyle;
        public int dwExStyle;
        public int dwWindowStatus;
        public int cxWindowBorders;
        public int cyWindowBorders;
        public short atomWindowType;
        public short wCreatorVersion;

        public WINDOWINFO() {
            super();
        }

        public WINDOWINFO(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }

        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cbSize", "rcWindow", "rcClient", "dwStyle", "dwExStyle", "dwWindowStatus", "cxWindowBorders", "cyWindowBorders", "atomWindowType", "wCreatorVersion"});
        }
    }

    public static class RECT extends Structure {
        public NativeLong left;
        public NativeLong top;
        public NativeLong right;
        public NativeLong bottom;

        public RECT() {
            super();
        }

        public RECT(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }

        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"left", "top", "right", "bottom"});
        }
    }
```

I am working with the WinAPI using Java and the JNA library. User32 is used to call the above calls.

Any help would be appreciated. I cannot find a lot of info related to why this is happening (even on the WinAPI documentation). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating instances of your classes, and then manually calling `getPointer()` on them to allocate native memory to give to the Win32 API to populate, but you are not `read()`'ing that native memory back into your class members afterwards, which is why the members remain all zeros after the functions have exited.

Per the [`getPointer()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#getPointer--) documentation:

> Return a [`Pointer`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html) object to this structure. **Note that if you use the structure's pointer as a function argument, you are responsible for calling [`write()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#write--) prior to the call and [`read()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#read--) after the call.** These calls are normally handled automatically by the [`Function`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Function.html) object when it encounters a [`Structure`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) argument or return value. The returned pointer may not have meaning for [`Structure.ByValue`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.ByValue.html) structure representations.

For example:

```java
WinAPI.WINDOWINFO windowInfo = new WinAPI.WINDOWINFO();
windowInfo.write(); // <-- add this
System.out.println("result of GetWindowInfo: " + user32.GetWindowInfo(windowHandle, windowInfo.getPointer()));
windowInfo.read(); // <-- add this
...
WinAPI.RECT r = new WinAPI.RECT();
//r.write(); // <-- optional in this case
System.out.println("result of GetWindowRect: " + user32.GetWindowRect(windowHandle, r.getPointer()));
r.read(); // <-- add this
```

Otherwise, you should change the declaration of `user32.GetWindowInfo()` to take a `WinAPI.WINDOWINFO` parameter instead of a `Pointer` parameter.  Same with `user32.GetWindowRect()` and `WinAPI.RECT`.  Let JNA handle the serialization of native memory for you.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that because I have to provide a pointer to the data structure in order for it to be populated. What would I do to read that memory back into my class?

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. I looked at the Structure documentation on the JNA API, and it has a "setAutoSynch(boolean auto)" method. I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately - the documentation claims it would do the read/write for you before and after native calls. I'm going to try your suggestion and let you know if it works.

Comment: Doing a "read" call before and after worked perfectly for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The `setAutoSynch()` functionality applies for a `Function` that takes a `Structure` as a parameter, not a raw `Pointer`. You don't need to call `read()` before a native function call, you need to call `write()` instead, in this case to write the value of `WINDOWINFO.cbSize` into the native memory.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant write before and read after lol. Thank you for your help.